# java.lang.RuntimeException and java.lang.classNotFoundException

Tags: c#, android, exception

I have two activities (MainActivity and SeconActivity):

```
namespace App16
{
    [Activity(Label = "App16", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate
            {

                var activity2 = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity)).SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
                //var activity2 = new Intent(this, typeof(EnglishWord));
                activity2.PutExtra("MyData", "Clicked");
                StartActivity(activity2);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
namespace App16
{
    [Activity(Label = "SecondActivity")]
    public class SecondActivity : Activity
    {
        Button button;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main2);
            //Toast.MakeText(this, "Hello", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            string text = Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData") ?? "Data not available";
            //string text = Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData");
            Toast.MakeText(this, text, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            button.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

and AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="App16.App16" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
  <application android:label="App16">
    <activity
  android:name=".MainActivity" >
      <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity" >
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I have this Error:

> java.lang.runtimeexception: unable to instantiate activity componentInfo {app16.app16/app16.app16.mainactivity}: java.lang.classnotfoundexception: Did not find class "app16.app16.mainactivity" on path:/data/app/app16.app16-1.apk

With `android:name="App16.App16.MainActivity"` I do not have any output in emulator.

Comment: This is not c#,isn't it?

Comment: @Pikoh This does seem to be C# code, but I'm not sure how OP is getting Java related errors.

Comment: That's why i'm asking @stijn. I removed the c# tag, but now i'm not sure (have not used Xamarin)

Comment: I use VS 2012 for android.

Comment: Then I think you should add the `Xamarin.android` tag :

Comment: Where do I add Xamarin.android?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt package be just App16 here?

```
package="App16.App16"
```

Comment: I have package="App16.App16" in AndroidManifest

Comment: Yes and the manifest package declaration (= App16.App16) doesn't match the namespace of your MainActivity (=App16)

Comment: Why name of the package is App16.App16?

Comment: I am guessing that is a question for whoever wrote the Manifest xml file. I am saying you need to correct the manifest file to use the correct namespace, which is just App16 and not App16.App16

Comment: I changed package="App16.App16" to  package="App16" in Manifest but I see the same Error.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace

Comment: I changed my program but I see the same Errors. I see these: http://w28i.imgup.net/E1eb51.png and http://u15i.imgup.net/E3a37d.png. They are enough?

Comment: Same error different class. Please make the changes for classes checking their namespace